phpがダウンロードされてしまう（Nginx）
症状を話すと、アクセスすると、phpがダウンロードされる問題が発生しています。
例：example.com/wordpress/wp-login → ダウンロードされる
example.com でWordPressにリダイレクトするように設定されています。
それも勝手にダウンロードされてしまうのです。
知ってる方は教えて下さい。
nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress.conf;
}


例えば検索で見つかるこの辺の記事で解説されている設定の手順やファイル内容は確かめてみましたか？ nginx と PHP-FPM を連携する, 【初心者向け】PHPとNginxの組み合わせを10ステップで解説, NginxでPHPを動かす！Apacheとの違いや設定方法を紹介, nginx で PHP を動かす

nginx自体には静的コンテンツの表示機能しかありません。この機能は、サーバー上にあるファイルをそのままアクセス先に渡すというものです。HTML、CSS、JavaScript、PNGやJPEGといった画像等の静的コンテンツのみで構成されたWebページであれば、nginxのみで対応が可能ですが、PHPのような動的コンテンツを表示させたい場合はnginxだけでは不十分です。もし、nginxしかインストールしていない場合は、PHP等もただの静的コンテンツとして扱われ、ファイルそのものを表示やブラウザーによってはダウンロードとなるでしょう。
nginxでPHPを動的コンテンツとして扱いたいのであれば、FastCGIという仕組みを使ってPHPのエンジンを結びつける必要があります。まず、PHPのFastCGI Process Manager (FPM)が必要です。これはPHPのFastCGI実装であり、Linuxの多くのディストリビューションではphp-fpmパッケージで提供されています。PHP FPMはインストールするだけでは不十分です。次の事をしておく必要があります。

PHP FPMのデーモンをサービスとして実行しておく。
nginxの設定で.phpファイルへのアクセスをPHP FPMへのFastCGIアクセスになるように設定する。

でも、安心してください。ほとんどのディストリビューションではphp-fpmのパッケージをインストールすることで、PHP FPMのモジュールだけで無く、上の設定も用意してくれます。ということで、次の事を試して見てください。

まずは、php-fpmパッケージをインストールしてください。
PHP FPMのサービスが起動しているか確認してください。php-fpmをインストールしている場合、systemctl -l | grep phpと実行すればphp-fpmとかphp*-fpmとかのサービスがみつかるはずです。起動していなければ、startしてください。
nginx.confおよびnginx.confがincludeしているファイルでphp-fpmに関する記述があるか確認してください。ディストリビューションにによってはコメントアウトされている場合があります。その場合は、コメントアウトを外してください。

Linuxの場合、ディストリビューションやバージョンによって細かい違いありますので、実際のファイルなどがどうなっているか聞きたい場合は質問でディストリビューションとバージョンを明記してください。Windowsを除いて、Linux以外の場合もだいたい同じですが、詳しいことはOSとバージョンがわからないとなんとも言えません。
